# Cannot find "Workspaces" in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I just downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and cannot find "workspaces" on the right of the desktop display. If I go to Appearance settings, there is no menu for Workspaces.
If I use the <kbd>Super</kbd> Key there are no workspaces shown.

How can I turn on to have workspaces that are supposed to be in this version of the OS?

Answer (score 5):

In 20.04, there are two kinds of workspaces. Dynamic and static.

Dynamic workspaces are created as needed, and disappear when empty.

Many users find static workspaces a little easier to use. To enable them, start `Tweaks` (gnome-tweaks). If you don't have `Tweaks` installed, go to the `Software` app and install it, or in the `terminal` type:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

Start `Tweaks`, then click on **Workspaces**, select **Static Workspaces**, and define a number of desired workspaces (I have 4).

Workspaces are viewed/managed by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. Look in the Keyboard Shortcuts settings panel to view all of the keys that can be used to manipulate workspaces.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you happen to know how I can position virtual desktop relative to each other? I only use two, and I am not able to have them "horizontally" and not "vertically" (one above one below).

Comment: @AntonioSesto Are you asking about workspaces? Up until 21.04 they were vertical by default. In 21.10 they are now horizontal. Please start a new question if you have more questions.

Comment: You have answered my question, thank you very much.