# Empty workspace doesn't go away

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 without any desktop tweaks or add-ons. Somehow I hit a wrong hotkey and I'm stuck with a second, empty workspace and a bar on the right. How do I get rid of it?

[image]

**EDIT**

I have not installed (explicitly) any extensions:

```
paul@paul-desktop:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/paul/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
paul@paul-desktop:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug  5  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan 23 02:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  5  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  5  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: You don't. When using dynamic workspaces, it always keeps one empty workspace open.

Comment: How do I get rid of (hide) the bar on the right. It wasn't visible before my unfortunate keystroke sequence.

Comment: Have you installed any GNOME Shell extensions? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Please see my accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243305/cannot-find-workspaces/1243315#1243315 as it may help you too.  If it's helful, please vote for it. Note that if you click on `Activities` you'll see BOTH docks... that's normal.

Comment: @heynnema `gnome-tweaks` is pretty useful and setting workspaces to 1 static, removes the empty one.

Comment: But that basically nullifies the whole point of workspaces.

Comment: Yes, it does. I will increase this number when I find good use for more than one workspace.

Comment: Here's how I use my 4 static workspaces... I have Firefox in one workspace, Thunderbird in another workspace, and Liferea news reader in another. I always leave the first workspace empty, and I use that for transient things like terminal, etc. This way I can full screen each of the apps, and flip between them quickly, without messing with a lot of window manipulation.

Comment: I use the `Workspace Scroll` Gnome Shell extension to move between workspaces quickly. See https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/943/workspace-scroll/